# What's a folder with a green and red arrow in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. When searching files for symbols, I came across the following results:
[image] 
The bottom results have a symbol (on the right) of a folder with a green and a red arrow. What does this symbol mean?

Comment: Inteillij [icons reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/icons-reference.html)

Comment: What version of intellij are you using?

Comment: @Crazycoder please answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this means it is a junit test directory, but I can't find a reference for this info apart from [this very old answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207013635-IDEA-Icons-where-are-they-documented-).

Edit: [Version 2016.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html) of the icons reference shows the arrows as a test resource